# Is it possible to get facebook feed titles?

Tags: javascript, facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

i want to get all posts that i can see in my facebook feed. I want all posts of my friends and pages i like that are shown in main facebook page, not my own timeline posts.

basically i want a endpoint like this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/user/home

I want to get link titles, or posts texts. Is there any graph api endpoint to get that? I only can find endpoints to a single user or page posts.
[image]

For example, i want the text: "Playstation Australia is giving away....", its link, etc.

Comment: If you have the link, you can get the title as og:title from open graph protocol, check https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ for testing

Comment: There is no way to get the full home view of a user any more.